# How to format the content of the file in notepad++ using regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file `abc.txt` which has data like this when I opened up in notepad++

```
10.114.128.196, 10.149.53.72, 40.169.74.47
```

Is there any way I can make it like this using regular expressions in notepad++?

```
10.114.128.196,abc
10.149.53.72,abc
40.169.74.47,abc
```

Comment: yes it's a fix value for all the addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for

```
(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})[,\s]*
```

and replace with

```
$1,abc\n
```

`(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})` matches 1 to 3 digits followed by 3 more such groups starting with a ".". Because of the round brackets around the found pattern is stored in capturing group 1, you can reuse this matched text in the replacement by inserting `$1`.

`[,\s]*` matches zero or more commas and whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Global replace ", " with ",abc\n"?

Answer (score 0):

On the field search put: `((\d+\.?){4}(.)( ?))`

On the field replace put: `$1abc\r\n`

The last line will not have a comma `,` so I think it is ok to have just this one to fix ;)